# Java Rmi stub object life time

Tags: java, rmi

When a java-rmi stub object become invalid.

1-After link between client and server broken.(Is stub is valid after connection reestablish or it is still need to refresh)

2-After a specific timeout.

I want to get stubs ones and store them on application scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. It becomes invalid when the corresponding remote object is unexported, which can only happen if the remote object is unexported, either explicitly or as a result of local garbage-collection. Local GC in turn can only happen after Distributed Garbage Collection (DGC) has occurred, which means that for each client of the remote object, either it has allowed its stub to be locally GC'd in its own JVM *or* it has become disconnected from the network path to the remote object's host for long enough for DGC expiry to take effect, which takes a configurable time which by default is (was?) 10 minutes.

Comment: i didnt understand your answer a bit complex .Remote object is refering to stub or skeleton.

Comment: @ayengin (a) it's a complex topic. (b) Again, neither. The remote object is the object that implements your remote interfaces. Typically it extends `UnicastRemoteObject` or else is exported via `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()`.

Comment: Let me clear ,I have a RemoteNodeImp class ,at rmi server and i am successfuly get a stub of it at cient side .I want to know when this stub become invalid .I am not using distrubuted jarbage collector.Should i try to use same stub while it valid or create a stup for each session of user.

Comment: @ayengin you are indeed using DGC whether you know it or not. I can only repeat, the stub remains valid until the remote object is unexported. If you use a 'stale' stub you will get a NoSuchObjectException. That tells you to reacquire it, e.g. via another lookup.